# Compiler error: '.class' expected

Tags: java

```
String sAge = scan.nextLine();
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

System.out.print( "what year were you born? >");
int iAge = scan.nextInt (sAge);
final double Cyear = 2014;
final double LEmax = 77.9;

System.out.println( "\nThe percentage of your life you have lived is " + int LEmax );
```

When I compile this, I get these errors:

```
C:\Users\PracticeMethods.java:54: error: '.class' expected
  System.out.println( "\nThe percentage of your life you have lived is " + int LEmax );
                                                                               ^
C:\Users\PracticeMethods.java:54: error: ';' expected
  System.out.println( "\nThe percentage of your life you have lived is " + int LEmax );
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me resolve these errors?

Comment: Please provide a **complete** code example which reproduces the error exactly. The code you have given does not have a class or method which causes other compiler errors other than what you are asking about. Also, the code given does not match the code shown in the error message.

Comment: and please change the title of the question.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a syntax error. Try this:

```
System.out.println( "\nThe percentage of your life you have lived is " + LEmax );
```

Notice that you do *not* have to say again that `LEmax` is an `int`, we specify the type of a variable only when we declare it, not when we use it. Or perhaps you intended to do a cast? if that's the case, then you should write it like this, surrounding the type between `()`:

```
System.out.println( "\nThe percentage of your life you have lived is " + (int) LEmax );
```

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly casted LEmax to an int. Instead of `System.out.println( "\nThe percentage of your life you have lived is " + int LEmax );` do `System.out.println( "\nThe percentage of your life you have lived is " + (int) LEmax );` with the parentheses around `int`.